# $expand not working for onpremise SharePoint 2013 REST APIs

Tags: sharepoint, odata, sharepoint-2013

I am working on SharePoint 2013 REST APIs for integration purpose. I have on-premise SharePoint 2013 instance and followed [How to enable JSON minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49679078/how-to-enable-json-response-for-sharepoint-2013-rest-apis-onpremise/49680438#49680438) to setup JSON Accept Type for REST APIs.

All the APIs are working fine with accept header as `minimalmetadata`, `nometadata` & `verbose`. However, OData filters $expand with minimal & nometadata not working and getting 200 OK with JSON response body without having expanded attributes.

If I change accept header to verbose I could see expanded attributes in JSON response.
Please have a look on below sample request where expand not working for minimal and nometadata accept header:

```
http://mysharepointhost/_api/Web?$expand=webs
http://mysharepointhost/_api/Web/Lists(guid'xxx')/items?$expand=AttachmentFiles
```

All the above request with $expand works for me on sharepoint 2016 and sharepoint online.

Please suggest.